# Understanding something about divisible subgroups and generated subgroups

Tags: group-theory

[image]

So, that means that $dG$ is the intersection of all divisible subgroups of $G$ (that's the definition I know.) But then they say :

[image]

Here, I think they're saying that $dG$ is the sum of some divisibles subgroups of $G$. I don't understand how they came to this conclusion. Maybe they're using a characterization for the generated subgroup. I don't know.

Comment: Generated by a collection if subgroups does not mean intersection if those groups; it means the smallest subgroup containing each of those subgroups.

Comment: Isn't that equivalent?

Comment: You are getting confused. The subgroup generated by the divisible subgroups is the smallest subgroup that contains all of the divisible subgroups. Their intersection is the largest subgroup that is contained in all of the divisible subgroups.